# What rules do Devas have to follow? Do human dharma shastras apply to them?

Tags: gods, dharma

It is well known that Draupadi had 5 husbands. Ordinarily, this would be a huge sin for human women. However, Draupadi was an incarnation of a Deva (Devi), particulary Sachi (wife of Indra). Specifically, Madhvacharya says she was the amalgamation of all the wives of the Devas.

Therefore, Vyasa in the Mahabharata says she was pure and could not be tainted by sin. Kumarila Bhatta says this:

> The unlawful intercourse of the five Pandavas with a common wife has been very well explained by Vyasa himself: "Draupadi appeared, in full bloom of youth, out of the sacrificial altar, and as such she is Lakshmi herself [meaning just opulent; not actually Vishnu's wife, Lakshmi], consequently, she does not become tainted by her intercourse with many owners." To the same effect, we have also the following: "The Brahmarishi pointed out her wonderfully beautiful form to be superhuman, inasmuch as the great souled beautiful one (Draupadi) became younger day by day." All this tends to show that she was not an ordinary human being; and hence she has been spoken of as 'superhuman' (and as such her actions are not to be judged by the ordinary standard of human proprieties). It is for this very same reason that Krishna himself promised to Karna that Draupadi would go to him on the sixth day (after having been with the Pandavas for 5 days). If it were not on account of the superhuman character of the woman, how could such an authoritative person as Krishna himself have promised such a transgression?

This shows that the Devas are not bound by rules humans are very much bound by.

What set of rules do Devas have to follow?

Comment: @sv. Lol, they are indeed hopeless: "There is no concept of a “god” in spiritual traditions, though it appears to have become a fashion to pattern even spiritual traditions on Abrahamic practices. Call it a colonial overhang!

And there are no rules or laws in Hindu traditions. The tradition is a spiritual tradition and based on individual experiences. Period!"