# Why does Vishnu marry two wives

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, rama, lakshmi, sita

Why does Vishnu marry two wives since in Rama avatar, when the demoness asks him if he will marry her he says that he already has a wife?

Comment: what are you asking? Mother sita was his wife, that's what he told.

Comment: I think OP is asking why can't Sri Ram marry twice given that Lord Vishnu had two wives @juztcode

Comment: but isn't that also obvious, every avatar is different, lord ram doesn't kill chettris as well like lord parshuram

Comment: Because he is following vrat called as ekapatni vrat. If a person is doing the vrat, he cannot marry another lady.

Comment: @Carmen Sandiego Lord Vishnu has only one wife Godess Lakshmi

Comment: @user2225190 - see this question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10773/who-is-the-seer-of-the-nila-sukta-the-vedic-hymn-to-vishnus-wife-nila-devi

Comment: Lord Vishnu has only Goddess Lakshmi. If you are referring to Sridevi and Bhudevi, they are both manifestations of Goddess Lakshmi for different forms of Vishnu. Eg Bhudevi and Varaha.

Comment: How many cells in your body are Married to you? Vishnu is All Buddy...if you are everything then isn't it Ok to magnify a few cells of yours and beautify them and make them your wife? The cells not necessarily biological :-) The correct way to perceive Vishnu

Comment: This is a dup. of [What rules do Devas have to follow? Do human dharma shastras apply to them?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36115/what-rules-do-devas-have-to-follow-do-human-dharma-shastras-apply-to-them)

Comment: @sv. That question doesn't help me, and it also doesn't have an answer.

Comment: Vishnu is a god while Rama is a human. You are comparing apples and oranges. So if the other question gets answered your question here is automatically answered.

Comment: @sv.   Never mind the question because I found the answer

Comment: You can write your own answer then.

Comment: @sv.ok i will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vishnu married two wives because he promised he would marry one of his wives in her previous births.

Also, when he marries them, it isn't a relationship of lust, it is bhakti(devotion). 
It says in this [site:](https://www.ancient.eu/Vishnu/).